# Adding headers onto rabbitmq c client

Tags: c, client, rabbitmq

I use [librabbitmq](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) C library to deal with AMQP-complaint brokers (RabbitMQ in my case) and i try to add headers onto the c client, for rabbitmq.

I modified [amqp_sendstring.c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/da9c2c109ad9740177adfc93e5e92cba92c56134/examples/amqp_sendstring.c)

```
amqp_basic_properties_t props;
    props._flags = AMQP_BASIC_CONTENT_TYPE_FLAG | AMQP_BASIC_DELIVERY_MODE_FLAG |  AMQP_BASIC_HEADERS_FLAG;
    props.content_type = amqp_cstring_bytes("text/plain");
    props.delivery_mode = 2; /* persistent delivery mode */
    amqp_table_t *table=&props.headers;
    props.headers.num_entries=2;
    props.headers.entries=calloc(props.headers.num_entries, sizeof(amqp_table_entry_t));
    strcpy(&(table->entries[0]).key,"id1");
    ((table->entries[0]).value).kind=AMQP_FIELD_KIND_I32;
    ((table->entries[0]).value).value.i32=1234;
    strcpy(&(table->entries[1]).key,"id2");
    (table->entries[1]).value.kind=AMQP_FIELD_KIND_I32;
    (table->entries[1]).value.value.i32=5678;
    die_on_error(amqp_basic_publish(conn,
                                    1,
                                    amqp_cstring_bytes(exchange),
                                    amqp_cstring_bytes(routingkey),
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    &props,
```

and in [amqp_listen.c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/da9c2c109ad9740177adfc93e5e92cba92c56134/examples/amqp_listen.c):

```
  132       printf("Num headers received %d \n", envelope.message.properties.headers.num_entries);
```

However the listener doesn't seem to receive any headers. Any body have any suggestions? Other sample code?

Comment: Have you checked from RabbitMQ Management panel whether headers are sent with messages? Have you tried to send message from management panel with headers manually set and receive that message with you modified consumer?

Comment: With hope it will help: look through this real-life headers usage from [php-amqp](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp) extension [amqp_exchange.c#L758](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/6ab0821ca4ff10f4fb351662c032a6de8388ab69/amqp_exchange.c#L758)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Is there a function to convert from bytes to char *? I did'nt see one in amqp.h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.key` member of `amqp_table_entry_t` is an `amqp_bytes_t` not a `char*`, so you should use `amqp_cstring_bytes()` to set it instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a function to convert from bytes to char *? I did'nt see one in amqp.h.

Comment: `amqp_bytes_t` can point to a buffer containing embedded `\0` characters. There is no function to convert from an amqp_bytes_t to a c-style string, though it would not be hard to create one.